# Does CSS Grid have a flex-grow function?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

**Is there an analog to `flex-grow` for the [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) property ?**

I'd like my grid areas to accomodate the content they receive but have some areas take more place than others like `flex-grow` for `flex`.

Practically, in the example below I'd like

- the `turquoise` to be invisible because it accomodates its content.
- The `footer` to be invisible as well because it has no content.
- The middle section take the remaining of the page like `flex-grow`.

More practically, I'd like this code:

```css
.ctnr {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "nav main"
    "footer footer";
}

.test {
  background: black;
  height: 1rem;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: turquoise;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background: grey;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="ctnr">
  <header>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </header>
  <nav></nav>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

To act like this code:

```css
.ctnr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.panel {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

header {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background: turquoise;
}

nav {
  min-width: 10rem;
  background: grey
}

footer {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="ctnr">
  <header>hey</header>
  <div class="panel">
    <nav></nav>
    <main></main>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

**Without** the `div.panel` and without adding any additional tag.

The reason I would like to do this, is a legitimate one, that extra `div` element is annoying me.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

CSS Grid offers the `fr` unit, which functions similarly to `flex-grow`.

While [**`flex-grow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) distributes free space in the container among flex items, the `fr` unit distributes free space in the container among rows / columns.

*From the spec:*

> [**7.2.3. Flexible Lengths: the `fr`
>   unit**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)
>
> A flexible length or `<flex>` is a dimension with the `fr` unit, which
>   represents a fraction of the free space in the grid container.

(Note that `flex-grow` is applied to *flex items*, while `fr` lengths are applied to *grid containers*.)

So in your grid, you have three rows:

1. The first row is the header. You want the content to set its height. So its height is set to `auto`.
2. The last row is the footer. You want the content to set its height. So its height is set to `auto`.
3. The middle row contains the `nav` and `main` elements. You want this row to occupy all remaining vertical space. So its height is set to `1fr`.

```css
.ctnr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;  /* key rule */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" 
                         "nav main" 
                       "footer footer";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: turquoise;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background: grey;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: orange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: yellow;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctnr">
  <header>header</header>
  <nav>nav</nav>
  <main>main</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vjp0rg1L/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the accepted answer, with my case: sometimes a `<header>` element, and always `<main>` and `<footer>` element would be present on the page, below each other; the `<main>` should always be stretched (i.e. `flex-grow: 1` but for grid)

I added `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;` to the parent. This works when all 3 are present but not when the `<header>` is missing. I fixed that by adding:

**The fix:**

`grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;` on the parent element
`grid-rows-end: span 2` on the `<main>`

**Explanation:**

The `<main>` will always take 2 rows.
The `grid-template-rows` is a pattern for an infinite number of rows, so row 1-3 are `auto 1fr auto`, 4-6 are the same, 7-9, ...
When there are 3 elements on the page, the `<header>` will take the first row with value `auto`, the `<main>` will take rows 2 and 3 with values `1fr auto`. The `<footer>` will start on row 4, which is a new start of the pattern containing `auto`.
When there are only 2 elements (so no `<header>`), the `<main>` will take row 1 and 2, meaning `auto 1fr`, and the `<footer>` will take row 3 containing `auto`

With header:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Without header:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```