# Equal width columns in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'd like to have the html below showing in n equal columns whether there are two, or three, or more child elements to the row element using css grid - Flexbox makes this easy but I cannot get it done using css grid - any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 474):

The common answer of `repeat(3, 1fr)` is not quite correct.

This is because `1fr` is about the distribution of available(!) space. This breaks as soon as the content becomes bigger than the track size. By default, it does not overflow and adjust the column width accordingly. That's why not all `1fr` are guaranteed to be of equal width. `1fr` is actually rather just a shorthand for `minmax(auto, 1fr)`.

If you really need the columns to be the **exact** same width you should use:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
```

`minmax(0, 1fr)` allows the grid tracks to be as small as `0` but as large as `1fr`, creating columns that will stay equal. But, be aware that this will cause overflows if the content is bigger than the column or cannot be wrapped.

Here is [an example](https://codepen.io/tcurdt/pen/bGVqWVe) that demonstrates the difference.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the only one that actually produces even-width columns.

Comment: "This breaks as soon as the content becomes bigger than the track size." - very valuable notice. Thank you!

Comment: I came here because `repeat(3, 1fr)` did not give the expected results and your solution works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @QMaster there is even a working codepen linked. Maybe explain what did not work for you?

Comment: When you don't know the number of columns you can instead do this: `grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 1fr); grid-auto-flow: column;`

Comment: How can I make content wrap?

Comment: @TrườngAn I think you can use word-wrap: break-word; https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: would you mind converting the codepen into [a stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?

Comment: The problem with this approach is it changes how entire grid is sized -- since `fr` is about distributing the space, the entire grid expands.

Comment: @greenoldman not sure I can follow.

Comment: Let's say your entire content takes 100px, while your screen is 2000px. Once you put "1fr", not only the space for cells will be distributed, but also grid will expand taking entire screen (on width) -- 2000px. I already found a solution, using inline-grid instead of grid :-).

Answer (score 151):

@Michael_B's answer is almost there.

```css
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
   grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

Gives you one row of equally sized columns in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari as of writing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's dynamic and it only needs properties on the main grid container.

Comment: This worked perfectly wheraes Kevin's accepted answer did not for me. For some reason Kevin's answer didn't distribute the width evenly whereas this did.

Comment: This worked best for me because I have a dynamic number of columns, so can't really use fractions & percentages (that I know of).

Comment: This didn't work for me. Seems like when content is bigger than it's container, it breaks the 1fr width. `minmax()` worked for me

Comment: Agree with @SergiyOstrovsky, `minmax(0, 1fr)` works well for my grid.

Comment: @SergiyOstrovsky I've updated this answer to include `minmax(0, 1fr)` instead of 1fr.

Answer (score 49):

Define this on your grid container. Sets up three columns of equal width.

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

Comment: Is there also an option doing this with using `auto`? :)

Comment: didnt work for me. columns where still squeezed and thus difference width.

Comment: As @Kevin says grid container, you need to have `display:grid;` on it as well.

Comment: *whether there are two, or three, or more child elements*

The question is asking about arbitrary number of columns, not hardcoded to 3

Comment: this doesn't fix the equal width columns,
it is good until the content of column start getting wrapped

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```css
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}

.grid-items {
   grid-row: 1;
}
```

Otherwise, here's a demo that may be useful: [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sk2jc1uy/2/)

To learn about the `fr` unit, see these posts:

- [Does CSS Grid have a flex-grow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45870323/3597276)
- [The difference between percentage and fr units in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090726/3597276)

Comment: that's still not working for me - columns take 100% of the width and are stacked one below the other - what am I missing?

Comment: @user1678736 Please mark answer as accepted (green check to the left from the answer) if it helped you.

Comment: Exact same problem here: 4 boxes stacked on top of each other in stead of *next* to each other.

Comment: @user63457, what's the desired behavior. How about adding `grid-row: 1` to your grid items? Or how about this: https://jsfiddle.net/sk2jc1uy/2/

Comment: @Micheal_B The desired behaviour is as the original question describes. Adding grid-row:1 to the child elements looks like the correct solution, otherwise columns will be stacked.

Comment: Yes, eventually I resorted to 4 times '1fr' to get the desired result (this design called for 4 columns only). One thing is sure though: 'auto' does not make the columns all the same width.

Comment: @user63457 adding `grid-auto-flow: column` removes the need to add properties to children.

Comment: Correct answer by @Kevin below.

Answer (score 12):

The question asks for **arbitrary** number of columns, not 3! So use this:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.grid-container > * {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This way, its children (selected using ">*" in css) do not need to have any specific class or even be `div`.

Example: https://codepen.io/dimvai/pen/RwVbYyz

Answer (score 10):

This allows the columns to distribute better, and the columns are the same size regardless of whether the size of the items does not adjust.

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(33.33%, 1fr) );
}
.item {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Full-Width with Responsive Wrapping**

None of these answers were full width or wrapped to a new row when downsizing on mobile. This is probably what you are looking for if you want something similar to bootstrap. Note the 200px is the lower bound where wrapping to a new row will occur.

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, calc(100% / 3));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple answer(at least in my perspective). I got this issue above answers not helped me. Here the code to divide 'div' into equal width and with required number of columns.

```
//CSS

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; // no of 'auto's will be number of columns here it's 3
}

//HTML
<div class="grid-container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

more info on grid can be seen here [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to distribute each list to take all the space that the parent grid has for it, instead of allowing the grid to automatically distribute the space based on what each list has as content.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-container .list {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="list">a</div>
  <div class="list">b</div>
  <div class="list">c</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

None of these answers worked for me, So I tried another way. In my case, item size is related to the content. Some contents are bigger than others, so all columns will not be equal. I just wrapped any item with another division that has 100% width and 100% height and that is working.

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That is worked for me and I hope to help you.