# Equal width columns (fit-content)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm not sure if I'm overseeing something obvious, but I need a layout where each row has equal width columns but automatically fit to content with a min width of the widest vertical column as shown on the below image:

[image]

In reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601564/equal-width-columns-in-css-grid)

Sample 1: Using flex-direction column and flex direction row with width fit to content will result in this:

```css
ul {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 2px;
}
ul li {
display: flex;
width: fit-content;
flex-direction: row;
}
ul li div {
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 2px;
margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>First column</div>
        <div>Second column</div>
        <div>Third column</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Data with length.......</div>
        <div>Data with length..</div>
        <div>Data with length....</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Data with length...</div>
        <div>Data with length...</div>
        <div>Data with length....</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Data with length..</div>
        <div>Data with length.......</div>
        <div>Data with length.....</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thats almost right expect the columns each has their own length

Sample 2: Using grid-template-columns with minmax column and flex direction row with width fit to content will result in this:

```css
ul {
display: grid;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 2px;
}
ul li {
display: grid;
grid-gap: 2px;
grid-template-columns:
    minmax(5%, 30%)
    minmax(6%, 30%)
    minmax(7%, 30%);
}
ul li div {
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 2px;
margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>First column</div>
        <div>Second column</div>
        <div>Third column</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Data dynamic length.......</div>
        <div>Data dynamic length..</div>
        <div>Data dynamic length....</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Data dynamic length...</div>
        <div>Data dynamic length...</div>
        <div>Data dynamic length....</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Data dynamic length..</div>
        <div>Data dynamic length.......</div>
        <div>Data dynamic length.....</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Second sample kind of does the trick except that it by default uses the 30% in the [minmax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax()), and if put `auto` in the second argument in `minmax` the columns will fill out remaining space and still not solve the problem

Is there any neat technique to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use a lsit for this task. IMHO compeltely wrong sue for a list.
2. `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content)` will create 3 columns with minimal row-size.
3. You will have an unintend wordwrap. That can be countered with: `white-space: nowrap;`

Your grid doesnt work as you create sub-grids. They render independently from each other. You must only use one grid to achieve what you want.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 2px;
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <!-- first row -->
  <div>First column</div>
  <div>Second column</div>
  <div>Third column</div>
  
  <!-- second row -->
  <div>Data dynamic length.......</div>
  <div>Data dynamic length..</div>
  <div>Data dynamic length....</div>
  
  <!-- third row -->
  <div>Data dynamic length...</div>
  <div>Data dynamic length...</div>
  <div>Data dynamic length....</div>
  
  <!-- fourth row -->
  <div>Data dynamic length..</div>
  <div>Data dynamic length.......</div>
  <div>Data dynamic length.....</div>
  
</div>
```