# css-grid auto column width

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm working on a UI with css grid and have been seeing a slightly odd behaviour, namely that if I define a grid with:

`grid-template-columns: 50px auto 50px`

I'm not seeing that grid expand to 100% of the width of the container as shown in this image:
[image]

If I make the content in the auto area wider to the extend where it would force the grid to fill the space, the problem seems to go away. But my understanding and in all the examples i've seen suggests that this template should extend to 100% of the width of the viewport.

Am I missing something here? certainly feels like it, any thoughts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your rule:

```
grid-template-columns: 50px auto 50px
```

The `auto` value sets the column width to the width of the content. `auto` means content-based.

So the total width of the columns ends up having no association with the width of the row.

```
50px + content width + 50px can be anything
```

If you want the columns to fill the width of the row, then use a *fraction unit* to tell the second column to consume all remaining space.

```
grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 50px
```

More details here: [Does CSS Grid have a flex-grow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45870323/3597276)